# Autocomplete many to many rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models with many to many relationship. I need to replace f.select with autocomplete. Anybody can help me? I'm still learning in rails.

**Model :**

medic_record.rb

```
has_many :lab_medics
has_many :labs, :through => :lab_medics
```

lab.rb

```
has_many :lab_medics
has_many :medic_records, :through => :lab_medics
```

lab_medic.rb

```
belongs_to :medic_record
belongs_to :lab
```

**View :**

medic_records/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :lab_ids, 'Lab Test' %>
  <%= f.select :lab_ids, @labs.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, class: "form-control" %>            
</div>
```

**Controller :**

medic_records.rb

```
def new
  @medic_record = MedicRecord.new
  @labs = Lab.all
end

def create
  @medic_record = MedicRecord.new(medic_record_params)
  @labs = Lab.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @medic_record.save
      format.html { redirect_to medic_records_path, notice: 'MedicRecord was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @medic_record }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @medic_record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

    def medic_record_params
      params.require(:medic_record).permit(:date, :therapy, :lab_ids => [])
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip using autocomplete and use [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

#### Chosen

Download chosen and save `chosen.jquery.js` in `vendor/assets/javascripts`, `chosen.css` in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, and chosen sprite images in `vendor/assets/images`.

Add to `application.css`

```
# application.css    
=* require chosen
```

and to `application.js`

```
# application.js
=// require chosen.jquery

$('#medic_records_lab_ids).chosen();
```

Or if you insist using autocomplete:

#### Autocomplete

You can use [rails4-autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) gem. After running `bundle install` add these lines to `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

**Controllers**

```
# medic_records_controller
class MedicRecordsController << ApplicationController
  autocomplete :lab, :name
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :medic_records do
  get :autocomplete_lab_name, on: :collection
end
```

**Views**

```
# _form.html.erb
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :lab_ids, 'Lab Test' %>
  <%= f. autocomplete_field, autocomplete_lab_name_medic_records_path %>            
</div>
```